# Regex to compare URLs with a wildcard that alternates ( http://example.com/user/*/profile )

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a user specified URL that has a wildcard in it, e.g. `http://example.com/project/*/account`

In this case * could be anything, a number, a character or anything else.

I want to get regex that would find a match for that. The location of the wildcard * changes and could be `http://example.com/user/*/title` or `http://example.com/user/*/*/*/delete` (just as an example, depends on the site ... so all possibilities should be supported)

Any ideas or suggestions on how to do this? I was thinking of just getting the regex code for any character and replacing all occurrence of * with that regex code. Then comparing that with the current URL to see if it is a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your idea should work.

It is the same way globs are implemented in the Python standard library. The glob is translated into an equivalent regular expression with the `*` and `?` wildcards translated into `.*` and `.`. In your case you would replace `*` with something like `[^/]+`.

The only problem with this approach is that you'd have to escape all the regex control characters so `.` needs to be replaced with `\.` and `[` with `\[` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [URITemplate](http://code.google.com/p/uri-templates/) to do that matching.

Instead of this

```
http://example.com/user/*/title
```

You have to do this

```
http://example.com/user/{userId}/title
```

You should be able to find a C# version of it or be able to build it yourself, refering the java code

Here's a link to java [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/springframework/web/util/UriTemplate.java.html)

But if you are looking to match the * instead of using the URI template, replace all the occurances of `'*'` with `'(.*)'` and create a regexp with that newly replaced URI. Then just do a regexp `test` or `match`